# Ruby MySQL Gem Can't Find Locate Mysql Socket (how to assign location)

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have installed the following ruby gem:
https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql

I get the following error when attempting to run a test script:

```
test.rb:20:in `new': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql::Error)
```

The reason for this error is that I am using lampp and my MySQL socket is located at /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

How can I configure the mysql gem to look for the socket in the correct location rather than what I assume is the default location.
I know I could use a symbolic link, but I would rather configure the gem itself

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
  socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

to the settings for your environment in your `config/database.yml`.